# Missing /Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php

Tags: linux, zend-framework, zend-db

So after some long struggling I finaly have the ZendFramework running. Now I'm trying to get it working with my database, but my error file is telling me the following:

```
PHP Warning: include_once(Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php): failed to open stream: 
No such file or directory .....
```

When I run `# ls /usr/share/php/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo` the only response I'm getting is:

```
Abstract.php Sqlite.php
```

`# rpm -qa | grep php` is returning this:

```
php-ZendFramework-1.12.3-1.el6.remi.noarch
php-xml-5.5.0-0.28.beta4.el6.remi.x86_64
php-bcmath-5.5.0-0.28.beta4.el6.remi.x86_64
php-pecl-sqlite-2.0.0-0.3.svn313074.el6.remi.5.x86_64
php-common-5.5.0-0.28.beta4.el6.remi.x86_64
php-process-5.5.0-0.28.beta4.el6.remi.x86_64
php-mysqlnd-5.5.0-0.28.beta4.el6.remi.x86_64
php-cli-5.5.0-0.28.beta4.el6.remi.x86_64
php-pear-1.9.4-17.el6.remi.noarch
php-5.5.0-0.28.beta4.el6.remi.x86_64
php-ZendFramework-Db-Adapter-Mysqli-1.12.3-1.el6.remi.noarch
php-ZendFramework-Db-Adapter-Pdo-1.12.3-1.el6.remi.noarch
php-pdo-5.5.0-0.28.beta4.el6.remi.x86_64
php-gd-5.5.0-0.28.beta4.el6.remi.x86_64
```

Comment: hmm check your library at the path `Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.ph` is it present or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at it I think you need the package `php-ZendFramework-Db-Adapter-Pdo-Mysql` rather than Mysqli.

I don't really understand the purpose of splitting the Zend DB adapters into separate packages like that. It's not like you get a big disk space saving. Installing this should fix your problem though.

Comment: I just wanted to close/remove this question since I found the same solution (after 3 hours of work...) Since this is still the right answer I'll mark this answer as accepted